# Unable to run shiny server pro in evaluation period

Tags: r, shiny, rstudio

I am trying to deploy shiny server pro on a ubuntu 19.04 machine. I opted for the 45 days evaluation period where in Rstudio provides unrestricted access to shiny server pro features for the said period. But after setting up the server, I found out in the logs that my evaluation period had expired just after one day of use.

For setting up the server I followed the following steps:

- Entered my details in the evaluation period form in this link https://rstudio.com/products/shiny-server-pro/evaluation/
- I received a link in my mail which took me to the page which contains the commands to set up the R shiny pro server in ubuntu. This can be found here https://rstudio.com/products/shiny/download-commercial/ubuntu/
- After following the steps,and changing the `run_as` parameter to my username in `shiny-server.conf` file I was able to get the server running. But found this in the logs:

```
[2019-10-15T14:05:28.424] [INFO] shiny-server - Shiny Server Pro v1.5.12.1023 (Node.js v10.15.3)
[2019-10-15T14:05:28.426] [INFO] shiny-server - Using config file "/etc/shiny-server/shiny-server.conf"
[2019-10-15T14:05:28.427] [INFO] shiny-server - Using non-persistent random cookie secret
[2019-10-15T14:05:28.467] [INFO] shiny-server - No authentication system configured.
[2019-10-15T14:05:28.469] [INFO] shiny-server - Starting listener on http://[::]:3838
[2019-10-15T14:05:28.478] [INFO] shiny-server - License type: traditional
[2019-10-15T14:05:28.539] [INFO] shiny-server - Licensing check succeeded.
[2019-10-15T14:05:28.541] [ERROR] shiny-server - Your evaluation has ended. Please activate!
```

I tried the same steps on an EC2 instance, but ran into the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for anyone facing a similar issue kindly note that I was able to resolve the above error by raising a ticket to Rstudio who acknowledged the same and were kind enough to provide me with a new trial period key